# Refused to load gap://ready because it does not appear in the child-src directive of the Content Security Policy

Tags: html, ios, xcode, cordova, content-security-policy

After updating to the new Xcode I got this error:

```
Refused to load gap://ready because it does not appear in the child-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

This is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="worker-src blob:; child-src blob: ;default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#A83AFA">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <title>My app</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <% if (process.env.TARGET === 'cordova') { %>
    <script src="version.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the full debugger log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gap: in the default-src, but you have to add it to the child-src too

Comment: Actually that fixed the issue and now app is launching, but if I turn it off multiple times rapidly (close the app and open), it launches to a white blank screen again. Maybe do you know what is it?